# Django Tutorial - install the previously cloned copy of Django

Tags: django

I was following this tutorial when this error occurred. I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what is going wrong here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/contributing/

> (djangodev) (base) XXXX@XXXX-MacBook-Air hello_django % python -m pip
>   install -e /path/to/your/local/clone/django/

ERROR: /path/to/your/local/clone/django/ is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+).

This occurred after entering the following code

```
% git clone https://github.com/XXX/django.git 
$ python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev 
$ source source ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev/bin/activate
~/.virtualenvs/djangodev/bin/activate 
python -m pip install -e /path/to/your/local/clone/django/
```

Comment: By the look of it, shouldnt you change the `/path/to/your/local/clone/django/` with the correct system path for your copy of Django?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a basic question... I don't understand what you mean by "with the correct system path" so I would appreciate it if you could explain in more details

Comment: In which directory or folder did you clone from github. Where did you execute this `git clone https://github.com/YourGitHubName/django.git` ?

Comment: In a directory called "helloworld." I returned to this directory and repeated the process but still got the same error message...

Comment: Once in that directory can you comment here the exact command you tried to run?

Comment: I added the commands on the bottom of the main text

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The last command should be as executed as follows (After you are in the directory from where you did the `clone` command)

```
python -m pip install -e django
```